# Does IE10 support FormData()?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I've read ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772723(v=vs.85).aspx)) that IE10 supports FormData(). But when I type this into the IE10 JavaScript console:

```
foo = new FormData();
```

I get the error, "FormData not defined"

Does IE10 support FormData() or doesn't it? Is there a trick to getting it to work in IE10?

Comment: This might help: http://caniuse.com/xhr2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can confirm that it does - running your code in the console on this page works fine.

I will therefore hypothesize that you are in Quirks Mode, and therefore the browser is pretending it doesn't know it to be compatible with said Mode.

Make sure your page has a valid `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start and no errors to fall back into quirks mode.

Comment: Thank you @Kolink! That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your webserver request "edge" compatibility mode. That may help preventing fallback to older compatibility modes.